# Which exception to use when file content read is wrong

Tags: python

**Background**

I have a simple function that goes to a folder and looks at all the json files and then in particular it looks at a field called `map_file_name` and ensures each json file has the correct value and if it does not I raise **Exception**

```
   def verify_all_file_name(local_download_dir: Path) -> None:
        expected_map_file_name = constants.PROD_MAP_FILE_NAME
        for json_file in list(local_download_dir.rglob("*.json")):
            if json.loads(json_file.read_text())["map_file_name"] != expected_map_file_name:
                raise Exception(
                    f"Map name in the File: {json_file} has incorrect map file name"
                )
```

**Issue**

I want to raise a more specific Exception but i am not sure which one i should use? I went through the [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) here but not sure which specific exception applies to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a matter of opinion, but `ValueError` is a built-in exception type that seems to work here. If you don't like it, then simply introduce your own exception type:

```
class IncorrectMapFileNameError(Exception):
    pass
```

Comment: `RuntimeError` might be a better base class (since the lookup depends on the result of a runtime value generated by `json.loads`). If the function were more general, indexing an arbitrary mappable value instead of producing one itself, you could also subclass `ValueError`.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong but isn't `ValueError` used  when operation or function receives an argument of wrong value. In this case i am not really getting an argument that is wrong in this case but coming across a wrong field name.

Comment: Very indirectly, you could argue that the path given to `verify_all_file_name` was invalid because the files it contained did *not* contain valid map file names. But your comment does push me, anyway, further towards using a custom subclass of `RuntimeError` in both cases I mentioned in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the closest builtin error is `ValueError` but if it is too general create your own by 2 liner class that inherit from `Exception`

Comment: I see this was already answered while I was typing